# Intersecting two geodatabases with ogr

Tags: ogr, file-geodatabase, intersection, ogr2ogr, st-intersects

I am trying to create an intersection between two different layers of two different geodatabases using ogr2ogr, but without success.

I have been using the following command line prompt:

```
ogr2ogr.exe intersection.shp .\Sea.gdb .\Roads.gdb -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_INTERSECTION(Sea_Depth.geometry,Roads_100m.geometry) as geometry FROM Sea a,Roads b"
```

But I get the error:

```
Warning 1: layer names ignored in combination with -sql.
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_INTERSECTION(Sea_Depths.geometry, Roads_100m.geometry) as geometry FROM Sea a,Roads b):
no such table: Sea
```

For ease of context, the sea layer is made of polygons and the road layer is lines. Intersection.shp will ideally be the resulting file.

Comment: You must either use JOIN http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html or to collect the layers into one datasource by writing a VRT file http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html.